# Difference between mean and tight

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, differences

I'm trying to guess if an English speaker says `mean or tight` when you are talking about a person who don't like to spend their own money.

Do you use different words depending on the friendship with that person?

**UPDATE 2019/05/18**

I'm asking for the use in UK but answers about how to say it in US are appreciated too.

Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: What research have you done with online dictionaries? The Cambridge suggests an answer to your question in terms of slang or formality. It also appears that there is a British/US usage difference that I was unaware of. In any case it appears that your question should be posted on English Language Learners.

Comment: In the sense of 'parsimonious', :'mean' is standard or formal; 'tight' is slang or informal, and mainly British.

Comment: Neither are used much in the US. 'cheap' is the preferred word in AmE. Are you asking about any particular region or about all English speaking regions?

Comment: As a BrE speaker, I would say that "tight" means being careful, not spending money unnecessarily. However "mean" indicates being resentful about spending money.

Comment: I agree with Mitch about "mean" and "tight."  In addition to "cheap," in the US one might also say "tightfisted" or "stingy."  I think "stingy" is probably the most common. If you don't know the person well, then it's better to be diplomatic: "I see that you are *careful with your money*."

Comment: None of the words described so far are complimentary - but "mean" is perhaps the strongest and most disapproving of all. Scrooge was mean. If you intend the observation as a compliment you might say that the person is "careful (with money)".

Comment: Thanks for your comments! @David, Cambridge dict tell me the meaning of the words and an example of use but I couldn't find the use of it by real speakers not academic. For example WS2 says that mean is the strongets and disapproving, this type of information is quite important for me.

Comment: WS2 is not a dictionary, and if he has an answer for you he should write it as an answer, not a comment. You don’t appear to have taken my advice by reading carefully that one word is informal (or slang) and the other is mainly British usage. That will determine how any individual uses the words. This site is not for expression of personal opinions or statements like “I do this”. And if I called a friend mean or tight, the expression on my face or the tone of my voice would count far more than my choice of word in determining whether he would punch me on the nose.

Comment: @David you can post your comment as an answer an I could mark it like correct..

Comment: OK, I've done that. But others are tight with their votes, and may be mean to me by down-voting ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UK/US usage**

It would appear from dictionaries that both these expressions are regarded as (mainly) British (which may explain the lack of response to the question, assuming most list members are from the US — I am British and was unaware of this). The evidence for this is entries in The Oxford Dictionary for [*tight*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tight) and [*mean*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mean), the Cambridge Dictionary for [*mean*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mean), Collins for [*tight*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tight_1) and [*mean*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mean), and the absence of this meaning in the (US) Merriam-Webster Dictionary for [*tight*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tight), although there is an entry for this sense of the adjective [*mean*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mean).

A more specific alternative to *tight* is ***tight-fisted***, which is listed in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tightfisted) and not indicated as British in the others. However, there is no point comparing usage of this to that of *mean* in a US context.

**British usage of mean and tight (or tight-fisted)**

Reference to the dictionaries cited above shows that *tight* and *tight-fisted* are informal or slang usage, whereas *mean* is not. This would have only a slight influence on the choice of spoken language, whereas it would affect the choice in written language.

**Subjective opinion on use with friends**

There are very few circumstances in which, as an adult, I would call a friend either mean, tight or tight-fisted, as this would be likely to cause great offence. (Children use the word frequently, however, but they have a heightened sense of what seems to them ‘fair’.) If I was really sure of my relationship with someone and felt it necessary or wished to needle them I would probably prefer a slang expression like tight-fisted to soften things, or make a play on their being Scottish (as I live in Glasgow). But tone of voice and eye-contact is all in such circumstances.

If you are not a native speaker, don’t even consider it.

Comment: This is an awesome reply, thank you so much. I love subjective opinion too because I think that this is the "real" away to learn a new language, with the opinion of the real speakears not just a book :-).